# Complete Re-Installation of USB controllers

Tags: windows-7, usb

My Windows 7 64bit PC has severe problems with USB-Controllers. Both keyboard and mouse are constantly detected (as shown by a "Found new USB connection"-sound) in intervals of a few minutes.
Then, at some point both devices fail completely (sometimes accompanied by a "failed to install drivers"-message at tray).

I wanted to completely re-install the USB controllers, but to my embarrassment i failed. It is as simple as that: When i uninstall the first USB controller from Windows device manager , the keyboard and mouse immediately stop working and i cannot proceed with the others:

[image]

So, is there a way to re-install ANY usb controller simultaneously?

Comment: Why do you believe reinstall the controllers will solve the problem you describe?  The problem you describe sounds more like hardware then software.

Comment: After you install driver then shutdown computer with power button and move mouse and keyboard to another port and power on for a test. Burn a bootdisk of ubuntu and run it in trial mode to see if there are any usb/mouse/kb issues occuring there to try and establish if its hardware or a windows software/driver issue